# How android application detects left and right SD CARDS in adevice

Tags: android, sd-card

if I have two physical sd cards "left user sdcard" and "right user sdcard"(as given in vold.fstab), then how will applications like filemanger, know that that there are two sdcards - "left user sdcard" & "right user sdcard".

can any one help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is **no official Android API support** (i.e. no special function in [Environment class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29)) for multiple external storages.

Normally second sdcard is mounted within the first one. (As per I noticed in Samsung Galaxy Tab)

Something like:

- First sdcard is mounted at `/mnt/sdcard`.
- The second sdcard is mounted into `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd`

So, Whenever you get external storage path like `/mant/sdcard/` You have to scan to whole tree structure..

Comment: +1 yes i am also sure about that no official supoort is available yet.

Comment: @user370305 : Thanks a lot for ur quick rply